# Github Pages Markdown Icon

Tags: markdown, github-pages, favicon, github-flavored-markdown

I am working on a simple markdown-based Github Pages website and I would love to have a custom icon. I know how to do this in HTML but would honestly prefer to just write basic markdown to make it easier to manage.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?